# Select ONCHANGE for SELECT elements

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Hi I want to make select option in which I want that if someone select the option it changes the image size currently I am using input box to type size like 100*250 and click on submit and it changes the image size but I want pre-defined image sizes so anyone can select the size without writing it..

**I want to use this** instead of `<input>`

```
  <select>
    <option value="0" selected="selected">Choose size</option>
    <option value="1">100*200</option>
    <option value="2">300*600</option>
    <option value="3">700*1000</option>
  </select>
```

**Here is my PHP Code**

```
<?php 
include("connection.php");

if(isset($_GET['title'])){

$page_id = $_GET['title'];

    $select_query = "select * from save_data where Title='$page_id'";

$run_query = mysql_query($select_query);

while($row=mysql_fetch_array($run_query)){

    $post_id = $row['ID']; 
    $post_title = $row['Title'];
    $post_image = $row['Name'];



?>
<center>
<h2>
<a href="pictures.php?title=<?php echo $post_title; ?>">

<?php echo $post_title; ?>

</a></center>

</h2>

<center><img id="myImage" src="uploads/<?php echo $post_image; ?>"  /></center>

<input type="text" id="dimen" name="dimension" />
<input type="submit" value="Submit" Onclick ="splitString()"/>



<?php } }?>


<html>
<body>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function splitString()
{
var myDimen=document.getElementById("dimen").value;
var splitDimen = myDimen.split("*");
document.getElementById("myImage").width=splitDimen[0];
document.getElementById("myImage").height=splitDimen[1];
}
</script>
</head>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get a select's value with something like this:

```
var e = document.getElementById("dimen");
var myDimen = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
```

After that you have to associate the value with some sizes. Eg. 1 will stand for 100 * 90, 2 will stand for 200*120, etc.

Hope this helps.

Comment: and what about select option how do i write it

Comment: Well you could either leave it as it is and make the conversion as I said earlier (if it's 1, width is 100 and height is 90) OR you can give it a value like "100_90", then split by "_".

Answer (score 0):

When you change the select, the page reload. The form get the select and see the selected value, finaly you print the good picture!

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">  
        <title>imageRedimention</title>
    </head>
    <body >
        <form name="formulaire" id="formulaire" method="get" action="">
            <select name="select" onChange="submit()">
                <option value="0" >Choose size</option>
                <option value="1" >100*200</option>
                <option value="2" >300*600</option>
                <option value="3" >700*1000</option>
            </select>
            <br>
            <?php
                if($_GET['select'] == '1'){
                    echo '<img src="Capture.png" width="100" heigth="200" alt="mon image">';
                }else if($_GET['select'] == '2'){
                    echo '<img src="Capture.png" width="300" heigth="600" alt="mon image">';
                }else if($_GET['select'] == '3'){
                    echo '<img src="Capture.png" width="700" heigth="1000" alt="mon image">';
                }else{
                    echo '<img src="Capture.png" width="200" heigth="300" alt="mon image">';
                }

            ?>
        </form>
    </body>


</html>
```

Comment: using this but It's not showing me image on new page. New page on has select box and text 'mon image' @LeCoq

Comment: hm, are you sur the path in src is good? if you see the alt message it is because he not found the picture. I try this code at home and it's running for me. Can you write your directory tree ?

Comment: I have used this in `scr="uploads/<?php echo $post_image; ?>"`

Comment: can you write the result of 
<?php echo $post_image; ?> please

Comment: `<?php
$post_image = "Capture.png";
//echo $post_image;

if($_GET['select'] == '1'){
 echo "<img src=$post_image width='100' heigth='200' alt='mon image'>";
}else if($_GET['select'] == '2'){
 echo "<img src=$post_image width='300'  heigth='200' alt='mon image'>";
}else if($_GET['select'] == '3'){
 echo "<img src=$post_image width='700'  heigth='200' alt='mon image'>";
}else{
 echo "<img src=$post_image width='200'  heigth='200' alt='mon image'>";
}
    
?>`

Comment: for print the picture you must write this `echo "<img src=$post_image width='100' heigth='200' alt='mon image'>";`